# Replicating the behavior of serde(with) in custom serializer

Tags: rust, serialization, serde

I have a custom `chrono::DateTime<Utc>` serializer written:

```rs
pub mod datetime {
    pub fn serialize<S: Serializer>(
        date: &DateTime<Utc>,
        serializer: S,
    ) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        // ...
    }

    // deserialize omitted
}
```

I need to implement custom serialization logic for a `struct` and I'm having difficulties emulating the behavior of `serde(with = "datetime")` as attribute on a struct field. What I'm trying to replicate:

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(with = "datetime")]
    pub timestamp: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

My attempt:

```
impl Serialize for Foo {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let mut m = serializer.serialize_map(None)?;
        m.serialize_entry(
            "timestamp",
            &datetime::serialize(&self.timestamp, serializer)?,
        )?;
        m.end()
    }
}
```

Results in an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<S as foo::_::_serde::Serializer>::Ok: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> <...>/foo.rs:95:13
     |
93   |         m.serialize_entry(
     |           --------------- required by a bound introduced by this call
94   |             "timestamp",
95   |             &datetime::serialize(&self.sent_timestamp, serializer)?,
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `<S as foo::_::_serde::Serializer>::Ok`
     |
note: required by a bound in `serialize_entry`
    --> ~/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.193/src/ser/mod.rs:1808:12
     |
1801 |     fn serialize_entry<K: ?Sized, V: ?Sized>(
     |        --------------- required by a bound in this associated function
...
1808 |         V: Serialize,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `SerializeMap::serialize_entry`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
     |
86   |     fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> where <S as foo::_::_serde::Serializer>::Ok: Serialize {
     |
```

Have I misunderstood the usage of `Serializer`? I am not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Why won't you look at the expansion of `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]` with `#[serde(with)]`?

Comment: Your code calls `serialize_field()`, but the error message speaks of `serialize_entry()`. Are you showing the error produced by your actual code?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion on the error message. I started out by doing “serialize_map” then changed it. I believe the issue remains the same regardless.

Comment: FYI, `chrono` has a `serde` feature

Comment: I am aware of that yes. The serialization I need is different from the default they provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, looking at the expansion of `#[derive(Serialize)]` with `#[serde(with)]` will help us see what exactly the derived code is doing, allowing us to replicate its behavior. This can be done by copying your code into the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0213ee727368b1d76d2be8ee553506c6) and using the "Expand macros" option in the Tools drop-down menu.

When looking at the expanded code, we see something that looks like the following (though I have cleaned it up significantly to make it more readable):

```rust
struct SerializeWith<'a>(&'a DateTime<Utc>);

impl Serialize for SerializeWith<'_> {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        datetime::serialize(&self.0, serializer)
    }
}
```

Therefore, the proper way to do this is to define a newtype that calls directly to the custom serialization logic. The full correct `Serialize` implementation is then:

```rust
impl Serialize for Foo {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        struct SerializeWith<'a>(&'a DateTime<Utc>);

        impl Serialize for SerializeWith<'_> {
            fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
                datetime::serialize(&self.0, serializer)
            }
        }

        let mut m = serializer.serialize_struct("Foo", 1)?;

        m.serialize_field("timestamp", &SerializeWith(&self.timestamp))?;

        m.end()
    }
}
```